# Caught error "NullPointerException" even though there is data for array list

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception

The caught error is "NullPointerException". But When I debugged, there is something in Arraylist data. The app did not stop, but nothing happened in response too. My code is like this:

```
 public void sendDestination_zhu(View v){
    tryconnect tc= new tryconnect();
    List<String> sR=tc.doInBackground();
    try{
        List<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
        data=sR;
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (FragmentHandler.this,R.layout.single_row,R.id.parkingplace,data);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: in wich line you got the excaption?

Comment: Stacktrace, please. Indicate where you get the NPE. Also, `doInBackground()` is something you should not be calling yourself.

Comment: You're either misusing the AsyncTask calling doInBackground directly and in the UI thread, or misusing the UI thread calling setAdapter from background thread. Also, I don't see a point creating new ArrayList and then assigning `sR` to the pointer thus losing the created ArrayList instance.

Comment: @DoctororDrive Then how can I fix it?

Comment: @AtulOHolic Yes, it is. And the sR is the returned value of doInBackground

Comment: @Jens In the line "list.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: So your layout does not have a view with id `listView`

Comment: You shold not call 

    List<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
            data=sR

you should better write

    List<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
                data.addAll(sR)

Comment: @Jens I changed it, but still the same caught error.

Comment: @laalto I have nothing after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the pointer in `List data` to point to `sR`. Remove the line `data=sR`.

Comment: It still didn't work and with same error if I did so .

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, most likely your doInBackground() get executed and you will get data in sR. But running directly your sR will be null. SO giving NPE. Try printing value using logs and see the value.

Comment: In the debugging, I could get value of both sR and data.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using Asynctask is wrong. The doInBackground method should be called by the Asynctask subclass we create on its own. One should never call it directly.

Please refer to an [example.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/)

What is happenning in your scenario is the below code gets executed even before Asynctask finishes and hence the NUll Pointer.

```
try{
    List<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
    data=sR;
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (FragmentHandler.this,R.layout.single_row,R.id.parkingplace,data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For this convenience only, onPostExecute() method is available in AsyncTask class. Please refer the link and many other available online.

Comment: In the example, there is no returned value. And with onPostExecute() method, I cannot return value.

Comment: I put all the list view and array adapter stuff in the onPostExecute and call it in the button method. Still with the error of "NullPointerExecute". Any ideas about this ?